# ArangoDB duplicate collection identifier

Tags: arangodb

I'm running ArangoDB in the standard docker container (arangodb-docker).  After creating an initial, simple development database, and creating some Foxx services, I shutdown the container by pressing Ctrl-C from the interactive terminal.  The shutdown appeared to proceed normally.  When I attempt to restart the container, I'm receiving the following:

`2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] INFO ArangoDB 3.1.14 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] INFO using SSL options: SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE, SSL_OP_TLS_ROLLBACK_BUG
2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] INFO Starting up with role SINGLE
2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] INFO file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 1048576, soft limit is 1048576
2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] ERROR duplicate collection identifier 11704 for name 'event_venue'
2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] ERROR error while opening database: duplicate identifier
2017-04-04T19:58:07Z [1] FATAL cannot start database: duplicate identifier`

I'm just getting started with a project POC using ArangoDB, and have not done that much work on this instance.  I've created a few databases, created about a dozen collections, renamed some collections and databases, inserted, updated and deleted some objects into some of the collections, created, modified and dropped some Foxx services.  At the time of the shutdown, the database was idle - I'm the only person using that container.  Immediately prior to the shutdown everything appeared to be working fine.

More details:

- I ran `docker pull arangodb-docker` to obtain the Docker image.
- To start the container, I **initially** ran `docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 -it -p 8529:8529 --name arangodb-instance arangodb/arangodb`.
- I shut down the container by pressing Ctrl-C.  Subsequently I simply use `docker start -ai arangodb-instance`.
- Pressing Ctrl-C in the interactive terminal session produced an output like this:

  `^C2017-04-06T01:39:08Z [1] INFO control-c received, beginning shut down sequence
  2017-04-06T01:39:09Z [1] INFO ArangoDB has been shut down`
- I made a dump immediately prior to shutting down the system.
- Creating a fresh docker instance as per above, and restoring the dump also generates a duplicate key error - so the database was corrupt before it was shutdown:

`Server version: 3.1.14`
`# Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529'`
`# Re-creating document collection 'comments'...`
`# Loading data into document collection 'comments'`
`...`
`# Re-creating edge collection 'event_venue'...`
`2017-04-06T02:12:55Z [25963] ERROR got error from server: HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error): ArangoError 1005: duplicate identifier`
`Processed 13 collection(s), read 3837 byte(s) from datafiles, sent 2 batch(es)`

What could have caused this?  Should I blow this container away and attempt to reload a recent dump?  Can Foxx development errors cause something like this?`

Comment: Just ran a disk check on my system, and it's clean.  No system problems otherwise.

Comment: This sounds like changes haven't persisted to disk, maybe the docker file didn't have time to save through a graceful shutdown? It would be worth making a new image I think.

Comment: The edge collection object causing the duplicate was created many *days* before the docker container shutdown.  During those days I did make some database and collection renames.  My suspicion is on that.

Comment: Yup, I've used Foxx for a few months now and have never had any duplicate identifier issues. Foxx is one of my favorite features of ArangoDB because you can centralize models and business logic right into the database layer. Maybe create an Ansible script to quickly rebuild ArangoDB Docker images whenever you need them, make them so easy to build that you can rebuild them with just one line of code. Good luck.